# Why does Salesforce automatically put the record Id in the Name field?

Tags: sobject

When I create an object, it automatically creates a name field. And when I want to create any record for this object from Salesforce create new button, it's okay. Record created.

But when I tried to create from some Lightning Component, or other places, the record is created, but the problem is it that the Name field has the record Id.

Why does this happen, and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I edited your question to make it more legible and to follow our guidelines. Please read about [ask]. If I have edited the question in a way that does not reflect your intent/question, you can [edit] it to make further changes to the question.

Comment: Are you writing to the Name field when you create the records?

Answer (score 11):

If you create a record via an API (e.g. Apex code) without a name value provided, Salesforce automatically uses the new ID of the record for its name. This is necessary because the Name field is always required. Make sure you're providing a Name value if you do not want the ID of the record to appear in this field.